# Number of rows in data.frame with `eval_tidy()`

Tags: r, rlang, tidyeval

I'm trying to get the number of rows for a `data` argument in the tidy eval framework. Any suggestions what I should put in the `quo()` function to let the expression evaluate to the number of rows of the data? I'm aware that the `.data` pronoun isn't actually a data.frame, and a solution doesn't need to use it.

In the example below, I want `q` to evaluate to `nrow(my_data)`, which should be 20 in the example below.

```r
library(rlang)

my_data <- data.frame(x = rnorm(20))

# Doesn't work
q <- quo(nrow(.data))
eval_tidy(q, my_data)
#> NULL

# Doesn't work
q <- quo(length(.data[[1]]))
eval_tidy(q, my_data)
#> Error: Must subset the data pronoun with a string.

# Works but requires prior knowledge of data
q <- quo(length(.data[["x"]]))
eval_tidy(q, my_data)
#> [1] 20
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Ideally, this should work with `data.frame`s of any dimension, including those with 0 rows or 0 columns.

EDIT: To clarify, I have no control over the tidy evaluation itself, which is why I'm looking for a solution that modifies what is put inside the `quo()` function. The data part of the tidy evaluation is guaranteed to be a data.frame though.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use a pre-designated variable name in the unevaluated expression captured by `quo()`, then assign your data frame to that variable name in evaluation:

```
myquo <- quo(nrow(.df))              # Choosing .df as my variable name
eval_tidy(myquo, list(.df=my_data))  # Assigning my_data to that variable name
# [1] 20

# Works with empty data frames
data0 <- data.frame()
eval_tidy(myquo, list(.df=data0))
# [1] 0
```

**EDIT:** To address your comment, accessing the data frame from within the expression is tricky, because the environment where the expression is being evaluated doesn't know about it. So, you have to step up through the environments until you get to where `eval_tidy()` is being called, which is where the data frame exists.

Here's a representative example:

```
myquo <- quo(
  environment() %>%             # The quosure itself
    rlang::env_parent() %>%     # The data frame, x is defined here
    rlang::env_parent() %>%     # The calling env of eval_tidy(), which 
                                #    knows of the quosure and the data frame
    ls()
)
eval_tidy(myquo, my_data)
# [1] "my_data" "myquo"
```

So, if you can't modify the `eval_tidy()` expression, but you know for certain what the data variable is called (`my_data` in this case), you can access it directly in the calling environment:

```
myquo <- quo(
  nrow(get("my_data"))
)
eval_tidy(myquo, my_data)
# [1] 20
```

Here, `get()` will walk up the calling stack until it finds the variable with the appropriate name, so extra care may be needed to avoid name collisions.

Comment: Yes that does help, but I should have clarified that in my scenario I have no control over the tidy evaluation as it is buried in the depths of ggplot2. I only have control over what I put in the `quo()` function.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, @teunbrand. Please see my edit.